# Event driven Kubernetes service

Tags: design-patterns, kubernetes, message-queue, grpc, messaging

Im looking for an inter-service communication solution.

I have 1 service and multiple pods with an incoming gRPC stream. The initial request calls out to an external resource which eventually triggers a request back to this service with a status message. This is on a separate thread and for this example ends up going to Pod B. I would like PodA to respond with this status message. I have tried to demonstraite this with the workflow below.

[image: service workflow]

The obvious solution here is to add some sort of messaging pattern but I would am looking for help in determining which is the best approach. The example below introduces a service mesh sidecar which would route external requests to a queue which Pod A would then subscribe to. If using AMQP, I would probably look to use [direct exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-direct).

[image: servicemesg-solution]

Any further information needed, please let me know.

Comment: Is the communication between your Pods and external service asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, but the response will not come back with the status. The status is pushed to Service A as a results of events triggered from the external resource.

Answer (score 1):

Pub-Sub communication between two microservices is a good communication pattern. The book [Cloud Native Patterns](https://www.manning.com/books/cloud-native-patterns) describes exactly this, and the advantage using this pattern over request-response in some cases. See chapter 12.

> 12.2 Moving from request/response to event driven
>
> 12.3 The event log
>
> 12.4 Event sourcing

This can be implemented with multiple technologies, but using [Kafka with microservices](https://www.confluent.io/blog/building-a-microservices-ecosystem-with-kafka-streams-and-ksql/) is a good fit. Kafka is also a distributed system, designed for cloud, similar to the principles used in Kubernetes.

**Your example**

To apply this to your example, the *queue* is the Kafka broker (or RabbitMQ?) and you need a way to post data from the *External Resource* to the broker. If the *External Resource* always reply to the pod that the request was from, a *sidecar* may be a solution. If the "reply address" can be configured, this could be an independent "adapter service" like e.g. [Kafka REST proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html) if Kafka is used as broker. There is probably corresponding proxies for e.g. RabbitMQ.